# Debian, Apache, mod_userdir, suexec, php-cgi

Tags: apache-httpd

I managed to configure Apache with php-cgi and userdir, I can access user
home pages with `domain.com/~userN/`. But everything is run under www-data user. I would like to enable `suexec` to run `.php` and other CGI files.

My question is how to enable `suexec` to work with `userdir` module? What if user directories aren't under one path, for example `/home/*/*/userN/public_html` and `/home/*/userN/public_html`. Everything under `public_html` should be run as user which owns the directory.
Apache docs aren't clear enough to me and I cannot make this work.

OS is Debian Jessie and installed package is `apache2-suexec-custom`.